# Cant use typedef of one class in dll from another project

Tags: .net, c++, dll, typedef

I have written a dll in which I have `namespace VT` in witch  class `public ref class Database` in witch I have typedefs:

```
public:
        typedef System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary <System::String^, Database^>         SubkeyDictionary;
        typedef System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary <System::String^, System::Object^>   ValueDictionary;
        typedef System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair <System::String^, Database^>       SubkeyKeyValuePair;
        typedef System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair <System::String^, System::Object^> ValueKeyValuePair;
```

**When I add my dll to another project and write VT:: I cant see my typedefs, why ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typeset is more like an alias than a actual type and I will check shortly, but I suspect that this is not exposed as a .NET type that can be used from other assemblies.

However, all is not lost. Rather than using a typeset you could do the following

```
public:
  ref class SubkeyDictionary : public System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary <System::String^, Database^> {};
....
```

This will declare an actual type that you can then reference.

Comment: I just confirmed, typedefs are not exposed in the assembly meta data so you will not be able to reference typedefs across assemblies. Of course you can use them in all the normal C++ ways.

Comment: ref class SubkeyKeyValuePair : public System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair <System::String^, Database^> { };
  ref class ValueKeyValuePair  : public System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair <System::String^, System::Object^> { };

Comment: Error 1 error C3246: 'VT::Database::SubkeyKeyValuePair' : cannot inherit from 'System::Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>' as it has been declared as 'sealed' c:\users\vitobrothers\desktop\vito projects\vt.database\vt.database\VT.Database.h 37

Comment: I cant write in that way ... Any suggestion ??

Comment: @ViTo, mmm the only thing that I can think of off the top of my head for those cases is that you actually create the classes, not derived from the KeyValuePair<>, but implement implicit conversions so that the KeyValuePair<> can be assigned or cast (implicilty and explicitly) to/from your type.

Comment: So, there are no solution for my question ?

Comment: @ViTo, your question was why the typedefs can't be used from other assemblies, which I believe has been answered. I also offered a work around, you can use derived classes for the Dictionary<> types as I showed in the answer and for the KeyValuePairs which are unfortuately sealed as you discovered, you can write some simple classes with approriate constructor and implicit/explicit cast operators which will make their use transparrent for the most part, they will look and act like your KeyValuePair<> specializations.

Answer (score 0):

The typedefs are inside the class, not the namespace. Writing

```
VT::Database::
```

should do the trick.

Comment: vitobrothersoft.com/Downloads/VT.Database.dll here is dll